# Playing same sound many times C# WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, audio

I'm trying to play the same overlapping sound whenever a button is pressed.
I tried with MediaElement and SoundPlayer, but the music stops and starts again. I need to create a new instance, but creating new MediaElement() and adding to the Stage didn´t work too :-/

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

Check here: http://www.interact-sw.co.uk/iangblog/2008/01/25/wpf-concurrent-audio

Create multiple MediaPlayers in the CodeBehind.

Comment: I did not succeed with MediaPlayer, but with a new try with MediaElment, now works:

    MediaElement mp = new MediaElement();
    soundPanel.Children.Add(mp);
    mp.Source = new Uri(key_sound, UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute);
    mp.MediaEnded += new RoutedEventHandler(mp_MediaEnded);

Comment: @MayconSouza You may write this as an answer to Your question, not just as a comment.

Answer (score 0):

I had no succeed with MediaPlayers, but it works:

```
MediaElement mp = new MediaElement();
soundPanel.Children.Add(mp);
mp.Source = new Uri(key_sound, UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute);
```